# how long would it take to find AES256 encryption key if about 100 plaintext/cyphertext block pairs are revealed?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric, license-key

We have offline software and need to generate about 100 license keys for that. We are thinking of getting 22-digit random string from offline software and encrypt it using AES256 and give it back to the user. Once use enters the key the software will encrypt the same 22-digit random number using same key and match both cyphertext. The only problem seems is someone can figure out AES256 encryption key from plain 22-digit random number and 22-digit license key.

We explored RSA and PKV. Since RSA cyphertext are long, it's not useful for offline software. Not too sure about PKV.

We can disable software if wrong keys are entered more than three times.

Comment: Why are you using encryption?  At first glance, this looks more like a problem that can be solved with a good cryptographic hash.  Hashes are guaranteed to be one-way only.

Comment: Using symmetric encryption for license codes is a very very very bad idea. Because a hacker can simply extract the key from your program and then generate as many licenses as (s)he wants. Therefore my recommendation is never to use symmetric crypto for such a use case!

Comment: The encryption key is going to be on encrypted drive and not accessible to anyone. Assume no one can access the encryption key. Only problem is user is going to know 100 plaintext/cypher-text  pairs. From those pairs, how soon he can find out encryption key? If it’s more than 20 years, it’s okay for our need.